# Append element into nested list based on the index of the nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list which looks like this:

```
l = [[['0.056*"googl"'], ['0.035*"facebook"']], #Index 0
    [['0.021*"mensch"'], ['0.012*"forsch"']], #Index 1
    [['0.112*"appl"'], ['0.029*"app"']], # Index 2
    [['0.015*"intel"'], ['0.015*"usb"']]] #Index 3
```

Now I want to append the Index (and the word Topic) of the sublists into the individual sublists like this:

```
nl = [[['0.056*"googl"', 'Topic 0'], ['0.035*"facebook"', 'Topic 0']], 
     [['0.021*"mensch"', 'Topic 1'], ['0.012*"forsch"', 'Topic 1']], 
     [['0.112*"appl"', 'Topic 2'], ['0.029*"app"', 'Topic 2']], 
     [['0.015*"intel"', 'Topic 3'], ['0.015*"usb"', 'Topic 3']]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I removed them with regex in my code. Will change the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
nl = [[[*x, 'Topic %s' % idx] for x in i] for idx, i in enumerate(l)]
```

Or use:

```
nl = [[x + ['Topic %s' % idx] for x in i] for idx, i in enumerate(l)]
```

And now:

```
print(nl)
```

Is:

```
[[['0.056*"googl"', 'Topic 0'], [' 0.035*"facebook"', 'Topic 0']], [['0.021*"mensch"', 'Topic 1'], [' 0.012*"forsch"', 'Topic 1']], [['0.112*"appl"', 'Topic 2'], [' 0.029*"app"', 'Topic 2']], [['0.015*"intel"', 'Topic 3'], [' 0.015*"usb"', 'Topic 3']]]
```

Comment: Hi @U10 -Forward, thanks for your answer. One more question: How would I have to change the code if the sublists looked like this: ```[[['0.056', 'googl']], [['0.035', 'facebook']]]``` ?

Comment: @gython ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `for` loop

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i][0].append(f'Topic {i}')
    l[i][1].append(f'Topic {i}')
```